# Unable to derive Sollet wallet address using mnemonic phrases in Solana-web3

Tags: blockchain, solana

My understanding is Solana should be same as other blockchain, with the same mnemonic phrase and derived path, we should be able to produce the same public address. So, after obtaining mnemonic phrase, I wrote below code to check

```
const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
const bip39 = require('bip39');
const ed = require('ed25519-hd-key');
const nacl= require('tweetnacl');
const mnemonic = "<mnemonic phrases>"
let path = "m/44'/501'/0'/0'";

const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic); 
const derivedSeed = ed.derivePath(path, seed.toString('hex')).key;
const account = new solanaWeb3.Account(nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(derivedSeed).secretKey);
keypair = solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(account.secretKey);
console.log(keypair.publicKey);
```

However, it gave me a completely different public address from my sollet wallet. Any idea of what went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're using a slightly different derivation path than the one shown.  Looking through the Sollet code, you may want to try a path of `m/44'/501'/0'` instead.  Check out where `derivePath` is used: https://github.com/project-serum/spl-token-wallet/blob/9c9f1d48a589218ffe0f54b7d2f3fb29d84f7b78/src/utils/walletProvider/localStorage.js#L25

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I tried it also doesn't work. Furthermore, I tried below:

Comment: Using Solana-CLI `solana-keygen pubkey prompt://?key=0/0` then input my passphrase, it shows my sollet address perfectly. If I understand it correctly, the key=0/0 should be identical to m/44'/501'/0'/0'. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I now used a stupid way which is generating private key with Solana-CLI and put it back to my program. However, I am still trying to figure why my code didn't work.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it would help.  Your best bet in that case is to just copy how sollet's doing it.

Comment: It is ok. Thanks for your time. 